# java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: while connecting to Ldap

Tags: java, ldap

I am trying to connect LDAP through java code but getting the following Exception. Can anybody tell me what I am missing? Here is my code-

```
 initialProperties = new Properties();
        initialProperties.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, initialContextFactory);
        initialProperties.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, providerURL);
        initialProperties.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, securityPrincipal);
        initialProperties.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, securityCredentials);
        initialProperties.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, authentication);
        try {
        context = new InitialDirContext(initialProperties);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {e.printStackTrace();}
```

Comment: The JavaDoc for ``java.net.ConnectException`` should be your first clue: ``Signals that an error occurred while attempting to connect a socket to a remote address and port.  Typically, the connection was refused remotely``

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed your code a little bit, and it works in mine.

```
public class LdapTest {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Properties initialProperties = new Properties();
    initialProperties.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
    initialProperties.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "ldap://192.168.0.179:389");
    initialProperties.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "cn=Directory Manager");
    initialProperties.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "dirmanager");
    initialProperties.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "simple");

    try {
    InitialDirContext context = new InitialDirContext(initialProperties);
    System.out.println(context);
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {e.printStackTrace();}
    }
}
```

Don't forget to start your ldap server first.